# Conditionally concatenate aggregated columns from different DataFrames into a new DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have several DataFrames with the following structure:

```
In [22]: arrays = [np.array(['A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2']),
   ....:           np.array(['B1', 'B1', 'B2', 'B2', 'B1', 'B1', 'B2', 'B2']),
   ....:           np.array(['C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C2'])]
In [23]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(8, 4)), index=arrays)
In [24]: df1
Out[24]: 
          0  1  2  3
A1 B1 C1  2  7  3  4
      C2  6  2  1  7
   B2 C1  3  3  5  6
      C2  9  6  3  6
A2 B1 C1  7  8  0  6
      C2  6  3  1  6
   B2 C1  9  3  8  2
      C2  7  1  2  8

In [25]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(8, 4)), index=arrays)
In [26]: df2
Out[26]: 
          0  1  2  3
A1 B1 C1  7  2  5  2
      C2  0  2  9  0
   B2 C1  2  2  6  9
      C2  4  6  3  8
A2 B1 C1  7  1  5  1
      C2  6  2  2  6
   B2 C1  5  8  1  6
      C2  7  4  8  0
```

I want to construct the following DataFrame.

`max` is the maximum value in the column '0' subarray;

`nth` is the 0-th element in the column '2' subarray if first-level index value contains '1' and 0-th element in the column '3' subarray otherwise).

```
             df1       df2
        max  nth  max  nth
A1  B1    6    3    7    5
    B2    9    5    4    6  
A2  B1    7    6    7    1
    B2    9    2    7    6
```

I tried `df[0].groupby(level=[0, 1]).max()` to calculate `max` and `df[2 or 3].groupby(level=[0, 1]).nth(0)` to calculate `nth` but stuck with concatenation using index values as a condition to select column 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my starting point (same code as yours, different random values):

```
          0  1  2  3
A1 B1 C1  3  4  1  6
      C2  6  3  4  5
   B2 C1  8  3  5  1
      C2  8  5  1  6
A2 B1 C1  8  7  0  6
      C2  5  1  4  7
   B2 C1  3  1  8  5
      C2  7  1  7  8
```

---

```
df[0] = df.groupby(level=[0,1])[0].transform(max)

          0  1  2  3
A1 B1 C1  6  4  1  6
      C2  6  3  4  5
   B2 C1  8  3  5  1
      C2  8  5  1  6
A2 B1 C1  8  7  0  6
      C2  8  1  4  7
   B2 C1  7  1  8  5
      C2  7  1  7  8
```

I couldn't find a way to directly check for a '1' in the first level so I just converted it to a colunn with `reset_index` and then it's fairly easy to use a string method on it.

```
df['one'] = df.reset_index().level_0.str.contains('1').values
df['nth'] = np.where( df.one, df[2], df[3] )

          0  1  2  3    one  nth
A1 B1 C1  6  4  1  6   True    1
      C2  6  3  4  5   True    4
   B2 C1  8  3  5  1   True    5
      C2  8  5  1  6   True    1
A2 B1 C1  8  7  0  6  False    6
      C2  8  1  4  7  False    7
   B2 C1  7  1  8  5  False    5
      C2  7  1  7  8  False    8
```

Now clean things up (some of which could be done earlier but I thought it more clear to wait until the end and combine it all):

```
df.iloc[0::2,[0,-1]].reset_index(level=2,drop=True).rename(columns={0:'max'})

       max  nth
A1 B1    6    1
   B2    8    5
A2 B1    8    6
   B2    7    5
```

I'm not sure if you're asking about concat also, but it's pretty straightforward:

```
pd.concat( [df1,df2], axis=1)
```

Comment: I found that we can say `df['one'] = df.index.get_level_values(0).to_series().str.contains('1').values`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to implement the solution I wanted:

```
In [55]: df = pd.DataFrame()
In [56]: for t, n in [(df1, 'df1'), (df2, 'df2')]:
   ....:     t['nth'] = np.where(t.index.get_level_values(0).to_series().str.contains('1').values, t[2], t[3])
   ....:     df[n, 'max'] = t[0].groupby(level=[0, 1]).max()
   ....:     # reset_index() is required since nth() doesn't reduce number of index levels
   ....:     df[n, 'nth'] = t['nth'].groupby(level=[0, 1]).nth(0).reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
In [57]: df
Out[57]: 
       (df1, max)  (df1, nth)  (df2, max)  (df2, nth)
A1 B1           8           1           7           0
   B2           6           3           9           3
A2 B1           7           2           7           3
   B2           8           2           6           7

In [58]: df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns)
In [59]: df
Out[59]: 
      df1     df2    
      max nth max nth
A1 B1   8   1   7   0
   B2   6   3   9   3
A2 B1   7   2   7   3
   B2   8   2   6   7
```